# Why is the property value not instantly updated when multi-threading? C#

Tags: multithreading, properties, thread-safety

I have a Task running which updates a Property in another thread.

The moment it updates it, inside a loop it rechecks the variable and often happens that the variable still isn't updated? (a second, two)

Here's an example:

```
while (true) 
{
     if (someProperty) // Fails to recognize the set variable of True.
     {
         // Do something...
     }

     someProperty = true;
}
```

Is it a multi-thread issue and those should be synchronized? What would be the best way to solve that?

Comment: To notify one thread from another use [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a loop and a variable check

Answer (score 0):

if this variable is shared between threads, it must be declared as volatile.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx